# What is the difference between "nächste" and "nächsten"?

Tags: difference, vocabulary, declension

As I checked in the the dictionary, both "nächste" and "nächsten" means "next" in English. So what is their difference?
If I want to say "See you next time", should I use "Bis zum nächste Mal" or "Bis zum nächsten Mal"?

Answer (score 4):

It's a question of genus and casus. Examples for neutrum:

"Das nächste Mal machen wir das anders." (Neutrum, Nominative)

"Im Laufe des nächsten Jahres muss sich etwas ändern" (Neutrum, Genetive)

"Bis zum nächsten Mal" (Neutrum, Dative)

"Auf das nächste Mal verzichte ich" (Neutrum, Akkusative)

and so forth for masculine and feminine nouns. See for example [here](https://www.korrekturen.de/flexion/deklination/N%C3%A4chste/), don't be bothered by the word being written with a capital letter. ("Der Nächste" used as a noun means "the next [thing obvious from the context]" but the forms are the same.)

Comment: And also of numerus.